# node:util:246 throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('superCtor', 'Function', superCtor);

Tags: node.js, npm

PS C:\Users\LENOVO\Desktop\App> npm init
node:util:246
throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('superCtor', 'Function', superCtor);
^

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "superCtor" argument must be of type function. Received undefined
at Object.inherits (node:util:246:11)
at Object. (C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\fs-write-stream-atomic\index.js:20:6)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14)
at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1435:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1207:32)
at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1023:12)
at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1235:19)
at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:176:18)
at Object. (C:\Users\LENOVO\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\lib\utils\error-handler.js:14:19)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1376:14) {
code: 'ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE'
}

Node.js v20.11.0

I was Trying to run the command npm init command and i get this problem. Not only for npm init command this problem shows up even running other commands too. also i am unable to install package.json file.